FFT implementation gives incorrect output
I have implemented FFT/DFT that I intend to use for frequency analysis of an audio file recorded from a fan. Here's the input I get when using scipy's fft. As opposed to this, here's the output from my implementation.
So far, my code looks like this:
from scipy.fft import fft
import soundfile as sf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pydub import AudioSegment

def dft(filename):
    
    #read file
    audio_seg = AudioSegment.from_file(filename)
    data = audio_seg.set_channels(1).get_array_of_samples()

    N = len(data)
    n = np.arange(0, N)
    k = np.linspace(1, 1000, 1500)

    X = np.zeros(len(k))

    #generate sinusoids and calculate dot product 
    for i in range (0, len(k)):

        base_sinusoid = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * k[i] * n / N)

        dot_product = np.dot(data, base_sinusoid)
    
        X[i] = np.abs(dot_product)

    #calculate signal's energy
    energy_sum = np.sum(X ** 2)

    #find frequencies whose energy is more than 1% of the signal's energy
    present_frequencies = k[(X ** 2) * 100 / energy_sum >= 1]

    print("The following frequencies are present: ", present_frequencies)
        
    plt.figure(1)
    
    plt.title("Frequency analysis") 
    plt.xlabel("Frequency")
    plt.ylabel("Magnitude")
    
    plt.plot(k, X)
    
    plt.show()

and then I simply call the function:
dft(<absolute path>)

Apart from the image, I also output
the frequencies whose energy represents more than 1% of the entire signal's energy.
The audio file is recorded from a fan with 10 blades, and around 200 Hz is the expected fundamental frequency. The frequency content is supposed to go up to 1000 Hz.
What I suspect may be the problem is an incorrect frequency resolution. Since I generate my own sinusoids, I may just be selecting the wrong frequencies. In my opinion, instead of generating 1500 frequencies (line 8), I should be generating N frequencies, however that takes a very long time to execute. So, I've mostly tried changing the maximum frequency, and the width of the frequency bins, but to no avail.
I should also note that I've used this function before on audio files where I say a vowel for 3 seconds, and it generated a correct output. The only difference there was in line 8, where I set the maximum frequency to be 20000.
Thank you for your time and insight!
EDIT: I added comments to the code, as well as improvements on how I calculate the energy. Thank you @GaTe for your suggestions! I should also add that I'm not allowed to use scipy's fft or fftfreq.

If the DFT, k is an integer in the range 0..N-1. You cannot pick arbitrary values for k as you’re doing.

I suggest three modifications:

Replace the linspace since you can use the exact frequency bins given by the FFT like that.
Calculating N manually for each frequency is indeed very slow. You can exploit the FFT algorithm itself.
Frequency bins should be more closely aligned for N.

This is the modified code:
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
import soundfile as sf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pydub import AudioSegment

def fft_analysis(filename):
    # Load audio file
    audio_seg = AudioSegment.from_file(filename)
    data = np.array(audio_seg.set_channels(1).get_array_of_samples())

    # Number of samples in the signal
    N = len(data)
    
    # Perform FFT
    X = fft(data)
    
    # Compute the frequencies corresponding to the FFT output
    freqs = fftfreq(N, 1.0 / audio_seg.frame_rate)
    
    # Only take the positive frequencies
    pos_indices = np.where(freqs >= 0)
    freqs = freqs[pos_indices]
    X = np.abs(X[pos_indices])

    # Calculate the total energy of the signal
    energy_sum = np.sum(X ** 2)

    # Find frequencies with energy more than 1% of the total energy
    significant_freqs = freqs[(X ** 2) * 100 / energy_sum >= 1]

    print("The following frequencies are present: ", significant_freqs)

    # Plot the frequency spectrum
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.plot(freqs, X)
    plt.title("Frequency analysis")
    plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
    plt.ylabel("Magnitude")
    plt.xlim(0, 1000)  # Limit the x-axis to 1000 Hz for clarity
    plt.show()

fft_analysis("<absolute path>")


Thank you very much for your input! Unfortunately, I mustn't use scipy's fft, along with fftfreq. I did try following your example here, initializing my k as:
k = np.arange(1, ((N / 2) - 1), 1 / audio_seg.frame_rate), however that makes k an array of shape (30302112000,), which is too much for my computer to handle.

since you cant really get the amount of frequency bins down without lowering your resolution(ofc, you can try if there is a sweet spot between quantity and quality). you could separate the overall array by iterating over it. Slice it to a size you are fine with and fill it with the new values, step by step. Could that work for you?
